# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Поставили ли Вы бы здесь запятую для удобства прочтения, чтобы не возникало искажения смысла?

При сохранении персонала (,) инвесторами рассматривалась возможность перепрофилирования производственной базы под выпуск газорегуляторных установок, емкостей и оборудования для СУГ — дополнительно к основному бизнесу предприятия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не ставила. Запятая тут на первый взгляд "незаконна".

Но!  конструкция очень похожа на факультативно обособленный оборот с непервообразным предлогом. Там как раз идёт речь о запятой во избежание двусмысленности:

> Оборот обособляется, если требуется обозначить его границы (чтобы
> предложение не выглядело двусмысленным):

[Во избежание неверного понимания фразы директором, были внесены изменения в документ. – Во избежание неверного понимания фразы, директором были внесены изменения в документ.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)

По-моему, похоже, хотя у нас и нет означенного предлога.

Посмотрите подробнее по гиперссылке. Всё-таки речь о нежёстком правиле, немножечко как бы на усмотрение пишущего.

Возможно, перед нами пример обособления предложного сочетания с первообразным предлогом? Но примеров я не нашла.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ссылку эту знаю... Здесь действительно предлог первообразный, так что запятая как бы и не нужна... Правилами она не предусматривается.